# JAVA - LocalDate.plusDay() doesn't work properly

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, java-time

I want to create method thatd add trainings which belongs to some trainingCycle to calendar. Problably I made some mistake becouse it's adding all trainings to only one day.

TrainingCycle model class:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "trainingCycle")
public class TrainingCycle extends Request {
private String id;
private String cycleName;
private Long cycleTime;
private LocalDateTime startTime;
private List<List<Training>> trainingsForDay;
```

Training model class:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "training")
@DynamoDBDocument
public class Training extends Request {

private String id;
private String trainingName;
private Integer predictedCaloriesToBurn;
private Integer burnedCalories;
private LocalDateTime startTime;
private LocalDateTime endTime;
private List<Exercise> exerciseList;
private List<TrainingLabels> trainingLabels;
private boolean approved;
private ActivityDay activityDay;
```

AddTrainingCycle method:

```
    public List<Day> addTrainingCycle(String userId, TrainingCycle trainingCycle, LocalDate localDate) {

    List<Day> days = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<Training> trainings : trainingCycle.getTrainingsForDay()) {
        if (trainings == null || trainings.isEmpty()) {
            localDate.plusDays(1);
        } else {
            Day actualDay = getActivityBoardDay(localDate, userId);
            actualDay.getTrainings().addAll(trainings);
            localDate.plusDays(1);
            days.add(actualDay);
        }
    }
    return days;
}
```

I've created test method and as I said - it's adding all of trainings but only for one day from argument, it's not increasing LocalDate. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 6):

`LocalDate` is immutable.

`localDate.plusDays(1)` does not modify the current `localDate`. It returns the new value which is current date plus one.

You have to reassign it:

```
localDate = localDate.plusDays(1);
```

Comment: Damn that was so obvious that I didn't even focus on that, thanks my friend!

Comment: You're welcome~

Comment: Well explained and precise answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words