# Calendar day adding not working as expected

Tags: android, date, kotlin, calendar

I am trying to write an algorithm that based on a number from 1 to 31 (a day in the month) it will return the milliseconds of the moment before that day/number.
The algorithm will always use today date.

Examples:
Input: 5
Output: 1601845199000 which is 4th October 2020 at  23:59:59

================

Input: 31
Output: 1601499599000 which is 30 September 2020 at 23:59:59

Because the month does not have 31 days, even if 31 is given the algorithm will take the closest possible date.

The same thing goes for February with 29/30

```
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()        
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59)
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59)
    calendar.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND)

    val lastDayNumber = 31

    var found = false
    while (!found) {
        if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) <= lastDayNumber) {
            found = true
        }

        if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < lastDayNumber) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
        }
    }
```

The problem is that `calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)` is not working at all.

This method should find the day before the number given in the future. Am I missing something? I've read the documentation and other StackOverflow answers and I still can't get it.

Edit1: I also tried with `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)` and also +1, however, -1 is working perfectly fine.

Edit2:

Looking at `GregorianCalendar.java` I see the following:

```
        // Handle week, day and AM_PM fields which involves
        // time zone offset change adjustment. Convert the
        // given amount to the number of days.
        case WEEK_OF_YEAR:
        case WEEK_OF_MONTH:
        case DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH:
            delta *= 7;
            break;

        case DAY_OF_MONTH: // synonym of DATE
        case DAY_OF_YEAR:
        case DAY_OF_WEEK:
            break;
```

If I take for example `WEEL_OF_YEAR`, the same code will run also for week_of_month and day_of_week_in_month, because there is no break all 3 fields run through the same code.

However, I see absolutely no code to run on `DAY_OF_MONTH`, `DAY_OF_YEAR` and `DAY_OF_WEEK`.

P.S. I cannot find `DATE` field

==================================================

Using `LocalDateTime`

```
fun getLastDayOfMonth(date: LocalDateTime): Long {
    val lastDayNumber = lastDay?.filter { it.isDigit() }!!.toInt()

    var found = false
    while (!found) {
        if (date.dayOfMonth <= lastDayNumber) {
            found = true
        } else {
            date.plusDays(1)
        }
    }

    return date.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
}

date.plusDays(1) is not changing the date variable to be next day ...
```

Comment: Why are you using this outdated datetime API? Any specific reason why you don't use `java.time`? What are you exactly trying to do? Just find a day or date? Could you explain it a little more detailed?

Comment: What is `lastDayNumber`?

Comment: Sorry, I added some more examples and an explanation of what I want that method to do.

Comment: No problem, but I still don't get what you want? Receive a number (which represents what exactly?) and find the day before? I'd love to help here, but I don't get the input and there's no desired result. Could you add examples for that, please?

Comment: @deHaar I edited the question again, you can read the top part, I also gave some examples and tried to explain it as best as I could. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I just read it and posted an answer... Hope it helps!

Comment: You sure, I edited it twice :)

Comment: If today is 7 September and I enter 7, should I get 6 September (yesterday) or 6 October? If I enter 8, should I get 7 September (today) or 7 October?

Comment: Ok, I seem to have missed the part that added the input as epoch millis... That changes the situation and makes my answer need edits. Still to come, but will take a while, I'm not at a computer right now.

Comment: @OleV.V. If you enter 7 and today is 7 September you should get 6 October. If you enter 8 you should get 7 September (today)

Comment: Thanks for providing all that information in response to questions in comments. It’s best to edit the question and add it in there so we have got everything in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `java.time`, which provides very handy methods for this.

See this example:

```kotlin
import java.time.LocalDate

fun main() {
    val fourDaysAgo = findDate(4)
    println(fourDaysAgo)
}

fun findDate(daysAgo: Long): LocalDate {
    return LocalDate.now().minusDays(daysAgo)
}
```

It outputs the date that was 4 days ago (executed today / 2020-09-07)

```
2020-09-03
```

`LocalDate.now()` calculates the date of today (NOTE: just the date part, no time of day, offset or time zone involved) and returns a `LocalDate` which has the method `minusDays(long days)` that correctly calculates *dates ago* by adjusting months and years if necessary.

If you do the following:

```kotlin
println(LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 1).minusDays(1))
```

the output would be

```
2019-12-31
```

If you need a time part as well and maybe even an offset or a time zone to really correctly subtract days, hours, minutes or any unit of time, have a look at the other classes in `java.time`...

**EDIT after the following comment under your question:**
*If you enter 7 and today is 7 September you should get 6 October. If you enter 8 you should get 7 September (today)*

```kotlin
fun findDate(dayOfMonth: Int): LocalDate {
    val now = LocalDate.now()
    val currentDayOfMonth = now.getDayOfMonth()
    
    if (currentDayOfMonth <= dayOfMonth) {
        // use the current month with the given day of month
        return now.withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonth)
                    // subtract a day (will change the month when dayOfMonth == 1)
                    .minusDays(1)
                    // and add a month
                    .plusMonths(1)
    } else {
        // otherwise just take the current month with the given day of month
        return now.withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonth)
                    // and subtract a day
                    .minusDays(1)
    }
}
```

Note: I guessed the case where the input day of month is less than the one of today, because you did not specify any behaviour for it. That case is handled the same way equal days of month (argument and today) are.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as I had with Calendar instance. I updated my question with code example.

Comment: I think I found the answer, seems that I have to reassign. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543514/java-localdate-plusday-doesnt-work-properly probably I had the same problem there

Comment: ok, I made it work although my algorithm is wrong :)), thanks you for your helping

Answer (score 1):

Here’s my go. Like deHaar I strongly recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. The `Calendar` class that you tried to use is poorly designed and long outdated.

Since you want the time 1 second before midnight, let’s first declare a constant with this value:

```
private static final Duration timeBeforeStartOfDay = Duration.ofSeconds(1);
```

Should you prefer one day, it’s easy to change it to, say, 1 minute, 1 millisecond or 1 nanosecond.

There are some corner cases we need to take into account. I think that this code does it:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    int dayNumber = 31;
    
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(zone);

    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from(today);
    if (dayNumber <= today.getDayOfMonth()) {
        // Next month
        ym = ym.plusMonths(1);
    }
    ZonedDateTime targetDateTime;
    if (dayNumber > ym.lengthOfMonth()) {
        // Use end of month
        targetDateTime = ym.plusMonths(1)
                .atDay(1)
                .atStartOfDay(zone)
                .minus(timeBeforeStartOfDay);
    } else {
        // Use day number
        targetDateTime = ym.atDay(dayNumber)
                .atStartOfDay(zone)
                .minus(timeBeforeStartOfDay);
    }
    long milliseconds = targetDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    
    System.out.println("Target date and time: " + targetDateTime);
    System.out.println("Target milliseconds: " + milliseconds);
```

It makes a difference in which time zone we run it. I ran it in Europe/Bucharest time zone since I imagined it could be yours. The output today (September 7) was:

> ```
> Target date and time: 2020-09-30T23:59:59+03:00[Europe/Bucharest]
> Target milliseconds: 1601499599000
> ```

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.